# Jhipster enhanced-resolve error

Tags: jhipster

I install `jhipster` project but when I run command yarn start it showing following error:

```
F:\projectname\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:48 resolveStep: withName("resolveStep", new SyncHook(["hook", "request"])),
                                                            ^
TypeError: SyncHook is not a constructor
    at new Resolver (F:\projectname\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:48:41)
    at Object.exports.createResolver (F:\projectname\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\ResolverFactory.js:107:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\projectname\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\node.js:20:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the error message.

Comment: Steps to recreate? If you believe this is a real bug submitting a new ticket in the GitHub repo would be the right place for this.